# How to get part of URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url

What's wrong with this? I want to output only `www.google.com`.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> window.onload=function() {  
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");   
   for (var i=0, n=links.length;i<n;i++) {      
     var string = links[i];     
     var str = string;  
     document.write(string);    
     var spl = string.split("/");   
     document.write(spl[2]);       
  } 

  } 

  </script> 

  <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></br>
```

Comment: Could you be more constructive? What output/errors do you recive?

Comment: Actually I Am Getting the value as  http://www.google.com for document.write(string);  but i am not getting any output for  document.write(spl[2]);  why this what wrong with that whatever but i need  to output only www.google.com not with the http://

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the href value:

```
window.onload=function() {  
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");   
  for (var i=0, n=links.length;i<n;i++) {      
  var string = links[i].href; //href value
  var str = string;    
  var spl = string.split("/");   
  document.write(spl[2]);       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery do it in that way:

```
var ancors = $(document).find('a');
    ancors.each(function(){ 
        var url_parts = $(this).attr('href').split('//');
        alert(url_parts[1]);
});
```

Comment: Cannot Do it Javascript? I Want In Javascript because my main script in javascript

Comment: jquery is javascript, it is more like a framwork, which reduces your own code by using the framework provided methods - Anyway you first should split on '//' and then get the second field of your result array like alert(spl[1])

Answer (score 0):

var url = links[i].href.replace( /^https?:\/\//, '' )

Comment: Did you mean to comment on somebody else's answer? I didn't link anything.

Comment: You're just posting a bit of code without any explanation as to why this is solving OP's issue. Please provide an answer instead of a line of code. There's a reason OP couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  window.onload=function() {  
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");            
var spl = links.split("://");
document.write(spl[1]);    
 } 



 </script> 

 <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://www.google.com";
alert(url.split("://")[1]);
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mE3y6/